# How to convert string "brakemeup" in to char[stringlength] array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, char

if i have this code, how can i put alle the chars in my string in to the Char array?

i know this wont compile but the logic shows what im trying to do.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stringX = textbox1.Text;

        int strlen = stringX.Length();

        char[] arrayX = new char[strlen];

        arrayX = stringX.Split("");    
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string stringX = textbox1.Text;

    char[] arrayX = stringX.ToCharArray();    
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind you can access the characters of a string by index using `stringX[i]`, so creating a new char array is often unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] arrayX = textbox1.Text.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
stringX.ToCharArray()
```